# Enable SELinux on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: selinux

I followed step by step the following guide to enable SELinux on Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS: `https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-enable-selinux-on-ubuntu-20-04-focal-fossa-linux` but after following the instructions the system fails to boot.

Comment: The instructions you linked ask you to put SELinux immediately into enforcing mode, which is a phenomenally bad idea. It is better to put the system into permissive mode first, and then work with the policy for a while until it is doing what you want before turning on enforcing mode. I mention this here as a warning to others who find this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If system fails to boot, it will be good to boot in safe/rescue/emergency mode.
once you have access to bash or sh prompt, edit the following file using VIM or any editor of choice.
/etc/selinux/config
look for the line
SELINUX=enforcing
change it to SELINUX=permissive
save the file.
Reboot the system and see if it boots up.

If it boots up then check logfile /var/log/syslog for SELINUX related messages.
This may give some clue.

You can also check /var/log/boot.log file and find out at what stage system booting stopped.